# Jquery swap divs on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I have got a small issue with the website I am working on.

I have a popUp div that is created dynamically and popUp windows needs to be responsive, so the problem is that I want to swap 2 divs inside that popUp when the width of window is lower than 768px.

I am not gonna pollute with my massive code but will simplify it.

```
(function($) {
function resize() {
var $window = $(window);
    if ($window.width() < 768) {
        add/remove classes
    }
}
function viewEvent {
    $("div.main_view").prepend("<div class='row popUp' id='popUp' style='max-width:700px; margin-right:5px;'></div>");
   $popUp.append("<div class='inner_boxed col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7' id='inner'></div>");
   var $text = $("div#text");
   $text.append(lorem);
   var $img = ("<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5' id='img' style='margin-top: 1.5rem; min-height: 250px;'><img src='img/train_deal.jpg'></div>");
   $popUp.append($img);
   resize();
}
 viewEvent();
 $window
        .resize(resize)
        .trigger('resize');
})(jQuery);
```

So at the moment, I get image after text.

So when the width reaches 768 and lower, I want my image appear before text and when width reaches 768 and higher I want it all back.

Comment: sorry, I will fix it, I have a variable for that var `$window = $(window);`

Comment: also function viewEvent {  should be function viewEvent (){   and what is $popUp.

Comment: is it essential? All of the functionality works. I am asking is there a way to swap 2 divs when you resize? I don't want to copy/paste all of my code

Answer (score 2):

to swap two elements next to each other you can use **.insertBefore()** or/and **.insertAfter()** something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).on('resize' , function(){
            resize('#div1' , '#div2');
   });

});

function resize(el1 , el2){
    var $window = $(window);
    if($window.width() <= 400){
         $(el2).insertBefore(el1);
    }else{
         $(el2).insertAfter(el1);
    }
}
```

[**Working Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/puq4bgvv/1/)

Comment: @AndrejsGubars sure you're welcome .. and what I meant about syntax error in your code ..you should know that javascript/jquery has more and more of functions to solve the different cases .. so may code work with your structure but won't work with another .. my code is very general just to let you know how to swap 2 element next of each other .. but if your elements is not next?? so this will not work .. thats why I was trying to make you post a working code without any errors to give you the solution for your case .. anyway .. Good Luck :)